# Java scientific math library to solve a string

Tags: library, java, math

I'm doing a scientific calculator app but I don't know which library I should use. I need a library that can solve scientific math expressions and if it can solve functions even better. I'm looking for one that works with a given string and solves it without having to parse any operator, like exponents or roots.

What library do you recommend me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript as a representation of your mathematical expressions.
It's a full-flege language, and all mathematical expressions should be possible (although I am not a JavaScript programmer, so I can't say that with 100% certainty). Additionally, [Nashhorn](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/), a Javascript engine, is built into the JVM so there is no need for additional dependencies. If you need something in a slightly different format than Javascript requires, you could easily make simple modifications to the user's input and/or add JavaScript boilerplate before and/or after it.